# getUTCDate() Function Issue in Different Time Zones

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I am facing very strange issue kindly take a look at two examples below.

**My Development Environment Time Zone: GMT+0500**

When i use following function:

```
var d = new Date("Tue Mar 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500");
var n = d.getUTCDate();
```

n = 17 which is correct (Return the UTC day of the month of a specific, local time, date-time) and everything works perfectly in my timezone.

**My Clients Time Zone: GMT+0000**

```
var d = new Date("Tue Mar 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000");
var n = d.getUTCDate();
```

n = 18 which is wrong

any one put some light why is that? how to resolve this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That answer looks correct to me. You enter a date in UTC, so the UTC date should be the same day.

Comment: Your date strings are different; why wouldn't the results be different?

Comment: The computer's timezone is irrelevant when you include the timezone in the date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> n = 18 which is wrong

No it's not.  You supplied GMT+0000, which is the same as GMT or UTC.  So the result from `getUTCDate` is of course the date you passed in.

I think you are confused because of how you worded this:

> My Development Environment Time Zone: GMT+0500
>
> My Clients Time Zone: GMT+0000

A time zone is not a numeric offset.  A time zone can *have* an offset, or *multiple* offset, and includes the history of how the offsets have changed over time.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

So those might be the *current* offsets for you and your client, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they are always going to be in the same offset.  If your client is in the UK, then they are at +0000 now, but they will soon be on +0100.  [See here for details](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136).

Answer (score 0):

Your first date is explicitly constructed with a time zone that results in the UTC date being 17.  At midnight of the 18th in the timezone 5 hours *ahead* of UTC (GMT), it's still the 17th in London. Your second date is constructed with the explicit UTC timezone. At the time indicated by your second date, in other words, it's 5 o'clock in the morning in the first timezone.